# Spring boot 2 with webflux and Router functions war does not work with standalone tomcat server

Tags: spring-boot, tomcat8, spring-webflux

The application runs fine on spring boot embedded tomcat 8.5.28 (gradle bootRun) but when I create the war and put the same in stand alone tomcat server (8.5.28) the application always throws 404 for any of the routes configured.

The application runs fine on spring boot embedded tomcat 8.5.28 (gradle bootRun) but when I create the war and put the same in stand alone tomcat server (8.5.28) the application always throws 404 for any of the routes configured.

Answer (score 4):

Spring Boot 2.0 does not currently support WAR deployment for WebFlux applications.

See the Spring Boot issue you created: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/12455